# Find element by xpath using only first part of attribute value

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have few elements which have in common only first part of attribute value, my question is, is that possibly to find list of elements by only partial value

below are elements:

```
<div data-fields="productLIFiveYr" style="overflow: hidden;">…</div>
<div data-fields="productLITenYr" style="overflow: hidden;">…</div>
<div data-fields="productLITwentyYr" style="overflow: hidden;">…</div>
```

and I am looking for something like this: `xpath='//div[data-fields="product.."]'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//div[starts-with(@data-fields, "product")]
```